# Undefined behavior while using vectors (STL), Please explain the below code output behind reason

Tags: c++, vector, stl

This one may well work with some compilers/OS, and crash with others. Same code with "List" it's working fine, While using "vector" only I am facing undefined behavior output.
Is STL (vector) is safe??

Note: This is not a real-time code, I am just going through some sample programs that's it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(1);
  v.push_back(2);
  v.push_back(3);
  v.push_back(4);
  for (vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin();
       i != v.end(); i++) {
    cout << *i << endl;
    if (*i == 1) {
      v.push_back(5);
    }
  }
}
```

Output with vector:
1
0
3
4
0
0
4113
0
858851888
943206709
2617
.
.
1
2
3
4
5
5

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  list<int> v;
  v.push_back(1);
  v.push_back(2);
  v.push_back(3);
  v.push_back(4);
  for (list<int>::iterator i = v.begin();
       i != v.end(); i++) {
    cout << *i << endl;
    if (*i == 1) {
      v.push_back(5);
    }
  }
}
```

Output with list:
1
2
3
4
5

Comment: What are you asking for? You have no question

Comment: So you're trying to edit the container while iterating through it - if relocation happens in std::vector, all iterators are invalidated so say the docs

Comment: `push_back` may invalidate your iterators, and then you're in undefined country. If you want to expand the vector while iterating over it, use indexing instead of iterators.

Answer (score 6):

The line in the loop:

```
v.push_back(5);
```

might invalidate the iterator `i` (in the case a re-allocation is needed), so since then `++i` is undefined behaviour.

One possibility to fix this is to reserve the vector first, so that the reallocation does not happen:

```
  vector<int> v;
  v.reserve(5); // reserve enough to keep all the pushed items
  v.push_back(1);
  ...
```

Comment: Invalidation isn't guaranteed; it's only if reallocation happens.

Comment: @UKMonkey Yep, I wasn't sure if the standard actually defines that, and it does (that the iterators are invalidated if and only if the reallocation happens). Updated the answer.

Comment: @axalis I added the quote from the standard which talks about this to my answer, but it would make more sense to add it to yours since it's the most upvoted. It's in section 23.3.7.5

Answer (score 1):

The concept you are missing is "iterator invalidation". `std::vector` is just a dynamic array with a finite capacity. When adding a new element results in an array size greater than the capacity, a reallocation needs to happen, and this invalidates all the iterators of the vector. This is defined in the standard draft, under section "23.3.7.5 vector modifiers", which talks about `insert` and `push_back`:

> Remarks: Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity. If no reallocation happens,
>   all the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid.

`std::list` on the other hand, is a doubly-linked list. So no reallocations need to happen to any of the elements already in the list, and only the `std::list<T>::end()` iterator is invalidated. But, since you are calling that method in the loop condition, your code just happens to work.